# What is the idea behind taking sequence of linear family $ \mathcal{L_n}$ in proving $\mathcal{L} \cap \xi_{Q}\neq \phi$?

Tags: probability, statistics, information-theory, information-geometry

I am reading 3rd Chapter "I-projections" of "[Information and Statistics : A Tutorial](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8187590)" by Imre Csiszar and Paul C.Shields.

In theorem 3.2, to prove $\mathcal{L} \cap \mathcal{E}_{Q} \neq \varnothing$, it is using a sequence of linear family $\mathcal{L_n}$.

Here

$$\mathcal{L_n} := \{P:\sum_{a}P(a)f_{i}(a)=(1-\frac{1}{n})\alpha_{i}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{k}Q(a),a\in \mathbb{A}\},$$

$$\mathcal{L} := \{P:\sum_{a}P(a)f_{i}(a)=\alpha_{i},a\in \mathbb{A}\}, $$

$$\mathcal{E}_{Q} := \{P:P(a)=cQ(a)e^{\{\sum_{i=1}^{k}\theta_{i}f_{i}(a)\}},a\in \mathbb{A}\}$$

Following are the snaps of the relevant pages:

[image]

[image]

I want to know what is the idea/motivation behind this to consider $\mathcal{L_n}$.

Comment: The last part of the theorem deals with generic $\mathcal{L}$ (i.e. which may have different support from $Q$). The proof is using the earlier part of the theorem about linear families with the same support as $Q$. In order to do this, they need explicit families with the support matching property. The $\mathcal{L}_n$ provide exactly this (first line after their definition), and so that proof applies, and you know that an appropriate $P^*_n$ exists. The relevant $P^*$ then exists via a limiting argument.

Comment: Also, LaTeX notes - the character for exponential family in the text is `\mathcal{E}` ($\mathcal{E}$), not $\xi$. The usual notation for an empty set is `\emptyset` ($\emptyset$) or `\varnothing` ($\varnothing$), and not $\phi$. Summation operators are denoted via `\sum` ($\sum$), not `\Sigma` ($\Sigma$) (this has significant typesetting differences beyond the size).  You can look up symbol codes via [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Comment: @stochasticboy321 thanks. And I have corrected the notations.